# Foreman and ESX Integration, docs and examples; rolling out VMs

Tags: vmware-esx, foreman

We're seeking a scripted/automated solution to facilitate rollouts of VMs in a uniform manner.  Since we use Puppet, Foreman is of interest.  However, there doesn't appear to be documentation (yet?) or examples of its integration with ESX.   Fore example, with VMware's CLI, you can poll for resource info,  specify which cluster and disk pool to deploy to, etc.  It's not clear to me whether Foreman can operate at this level.

Ideally, we'd like a solution that can oversee the entire lifecycle of the VM (or sets of VMs).  Presently, we use a kickstart.cfg to populate a VM with basic items, eventually Puppet will take over and manage that task.